# MBProgessHUD doesn't rotate anymore with iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, mbprogresshud

I've an app with `MBProgressHUD` attached on `UIWindow` that work perfectly in iOS 7.1.2.
But now with iOS 8 the HUD doesn't follow the rotation.

[image]

Is there a fix ?

Comment: Are you able to debug the code?

Comment: https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD/issues/233

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download last realese of the MBProgressHud

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD